# How to properly indent blocks using HughesPJ's pretty printing library?

Tags: haskell, pretty-print

I have a following programming language grammar:

```
data Expr = ...

data Stmt = SExpr Expr | SBlock Block | SLet Fundef | ...

data Block = Block [Stmt]

data Fundef = Fundef String [String] Block

data TopDef = TopFun Fundef
```

With following example syntax:

```
function long_function_name () = {
  let g() = {
    {
       h()
    };
    3
  } 
}
```

---

I am trying to use HughesPJ `pretty` library to create a pretty printer for this language. My attempts so far look like:

```
instance Pretty Stmt where
  pPrint = \case
    SExpr e -> pPrint e
    SBlock b -> pPrint b
    SLet f -> text "let" <+> pPrint f

instance Pretty Block where
  pPrint (Block stmts) = lbrace $+$
    nest 2 (vcat (punctuate semi (map pPrint stmts))) $+$ 
    rbrace

instance Pretty Fundef where
  pPrint (Fundef name args body) = pPrint name  <> parens (...) <+> text "=" <+> pPrint body

instance Prettty TopDef where
  pPrint (TopFun f) = text "function" <+> pPrint f
```

The problem is, I want to have `{` in the same line as the function declaration, but it always makes the indentation of the following lines relative to the column of the bracket instead of being absolute. Should be visible in the pretty print of the example above;

```
function long_function_name () = {
                                   let g() = {
                                               {
                                                 h()
                                               };
                                               3
                                             } 
}
```

Why does it happen and how should I tackle this problem? I would like to avoid as much code duplication as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re writing `<+>` before the body, so the `$+$` vertical concatenation is entirely within that horizontal concatenation of the `function` line, hence it’s all indented. I believe the way to do what you want with `pretty` is to explicitly match on the block, since it’s part of the vertical layout, i.e.:

```
pPrint (Fundef name args (Block stmts)) = vcat
  [ pPrint name <> parens (...) <+> text "=" <+> lbrace
  , nest 2 (vcat (punctuate semi (map pPrint stmts)))
  , rbrace
  ]
```

The more modern pretty-printing libraries like [`prettyprinter`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/prettyprinter) make this a little easier: `nest` (or `indent`, or `hang`) handles the indentation of lines *following* the first line in a vertical layout, so you can put the `nest` around the opening brace and body, and the closing brace outside the nesting, like so:

```
"prefix" <+> vcat
  [ nest 4 $ vcat
    [ "{"
    , "body"
    ]
  , "}"
  ]
```

⇓

```
prefix {
  body
}
```

(NB. you can use `OverloadedStrings` like this instead of wrapping literals in `text`.)

But that won’t work with `pretty`, which seems to be designed to align the heck out of everything.

I also recommend `prettyprinter` for its other advantages, for example, a `group` function that allows you to express “put this on one line if it fits”, which is extremely helpful for making formatting robust & responsive to different rendering contexts.